# Any point unit testing methods that use EF or Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing

I am writing unit tests for my service layer, and i completely see the point of creating unit tests to validate logic.  For example, if i create a function that adds two numbers, sure write a unit test for this.

But if in my service layer method i have something like this

```
public ICollection<MyEntity> GetAll()
{
    return _context.MyEntities
        .Where(e => !e.IsDeleted)
        .ToList();
}
```

What is the point in unit testing this?  Since i am getting this from a database, it seems stupid to mock the database, because i am then just assuming that Linq is working as it should be?

Would it not be better to test this against an actual "test" database with sameple data in it.  This way i can see if the number of record that are retrieved from the database match what i would expect?

I know that testing against a database, makes this more of a integration test, but is it really valid for unit testing?

What if i take another example, say this

```
public int Delete(long id)
{
    _context.Database.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE Id = ?", id);

    return _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can this function be unit tested?  If i mock _context.Database and create a unit test that checks if _context.SaveChanges is being called (which i see no point in what so ever), there is no guarntee that it will actually delete my data.  WHat if i have a foreign key constraint?  The mock would pass, but the actual method would fail really?

I am just starting to think, that unless a method actually calculates some sort of logic, i dont see the point/reason for creating a unit test, especially when using Entity framework?

Comment: You should unit test it to ensure that your Linq code is correct. What if you'd typed `.Where(e => e.IsDeleted).ToList();` by mistake, or someone accidentally edited it or otherwise broke it later?

Comment: Use mock for unit testing.
Using a real database is integration testing.

Comment: IMO in scenarios like this - where the test-code will soon end up more complicated than the production code - a good middle-ground are behavior tests ("after I added something to my database I can find it again ...") - but that's just [my opinion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVCtkzIXYzQ) (and I think that is a problem with this thread - sorry)

Comment: [it is fully possible to test entity framework code without a database.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to unit test nearly all types of functions:

"What is the point in unit testing this? Since i am getting this from a database, it seems stupid to mock the database, because i am then just assuming that Linq is working as it should be?"

- You are not testing Linq, but you are testing the function; the function has the name `GetAllAsync`; and simply I can assume that this will return all of `MyEntity` instances stored in database. But it simply returns only deleted items; unit testing is not just verifying if the function works properly; it is also a way to check whether this function is named properly.
- Also this function has a problem; what if

  _context.MyEntities(e => !e.IsDeleted) returns null? `ToList` will throw an exception. Then unit testing will help to identify potential problems if you test for extreme values.
- Also, unit testing forces you to employ abstraction. If you can not unit test a method, the method may have problems, you need to investigate that method and re-factor.

  _context.Database.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE Id = ?", id); In my opinion this line of code needs to stay somewhere else, not in the service layer (in repository maybe?). What if id is "-1"? how will you handle the exception?

I think it is really hard to state a generic rule about not unit testing methods that include `Linq`.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the naming, but was just writing a quick example. Point 2, see your point on this. Point 3, i dont have a repository.  Since EF uses the repository/UOW pattern, i didnt see the point of creating another layer of abstraction for the sake of it, it seems pointless.  Since this is my first project where i am writing unit tests for, its quite hard to figure out what to test, what not to test and how to test. Seems like i can write more tests than actual code?!

Comment: It's not another layer of abstraction 'for the sake of it' if it facilitates testability.

Comment: But if i create a repository layer, my service layer will call that. Ok i can now mock that when testing the service layer, but then what about testing the new repository layer? Do you mock that, or test repository layer against an actual database?

Comment: @user2736022: ideas presented in this answer are impractical. Of course, you can keep adding extra layers, but eventually you'll end up at the same place you are now -- with question remaining -- should you mock EF/Linq or test against real database? Keep in mind, that for such DAO-classes the only responsibility they carry is *talking to database*. Mocking this responsibility away will produce **useless** tests. DAO-classes are best tested against real database (as per Thomas answer) with integration tests, rather than unit.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you unit test a function that adds two numbers?  You're not testing the + operator any more than you're trying to test LINQ or EF.  You are testing behaviour so it's perfectly valid to test things that you might assume "just work".  If, for example, I banned the use of EF in your application, you'd still need a test to ensure correctness in whatever you replaced the function with.

Where do you want to draw the line?

Comment: add two numbers was simple example, but my point is, where to you draw the line? As i said in another post, you could end up writing more unit tests than actual code? If i find an error in my application, i write a test for it, it fails.  I fix it, the test passes.  Fair enough, but how can you write tests in advance for every possible exception? Where do you stop?

Answer (score 0):

For database related code, I would actually test against a real database, not a mock. It's the only way you can be sure that the SQL is valid (whether you write it by hand or let an ORM generate it for you). There are tools to make that easier, like [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/respawn).

Comment: @Downvoter: care to share your thoughts on why this answer is incorrect?